# jqGrid: Searching with json data

Tags: spring

I have succeeded to load data from server in spring framework with pagination but my **searching/finding** records and **filter** bar is not working.

But if i make **loadonce=true** then the filter or searching working fine.

My code for my jsp is:

```
var allColumnNames=["Sr. No","contactName", "city", "country"];

 var grid = jQuery('#list');

        grid.jqGrid({
            url:'customerData.html',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',               
            loadonce: false,

            colNames: allColumnNames,
            colModel: [

                { name:'id', index:'id', jsonmap:"id", width:20,index:'id', search:true, stype:'int' ,hidden:true},
                { name: "contactName" ,index:'contactName', width:160, search:true, stype:'text' },
                { name: "city",index:'city', width:160, search:true, stype:'text'  },
                { name: "country" ,index:'country', width:160, search:true, stype:'text' }
            ],
             caption: 'Customer Details',
                height: 'auto',
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],                  
                rownumbers: true
            });

           $("#search").click(function() {
            var searchFiler = $("#filter").val(), f;

            if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
                grid[0].p.search = false;
                $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
            }
            f = {groupOp:"OR",rules:[]};
            f.rules.push({field:"contactName",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
            f.rules.push({field:"city",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
            grid[0].p.search = true;
            $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
        });
```

I am new to jqGrid, Please help me in above problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you put **loadonce=true** jqGrid only makes one request that takes all the data, and then if you filter, sort, search... are controlled by jqGrid in the frontend.

But if **loadonce=false**, only loads the data needed at this moment, and every time jqGrid needs new data, it sends another request to the server with differents parameters.

[image]

So I can guess that your server file "customerData.html", it's not ready to answer all the different questions.

Here [http://trirand.com](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) there are a lot of jqGrid examples an most of them have the server side code.

Comment: thanks for the above.... but I have tried even that by filtering the data from server side but that's not working for me. So if you have some code that can be used for server side filtering of data that would be helpful.